# Transform the equation into a system of first order equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Transform the equation

$$\dfrac{d^3x}{dt^3}+t\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2t^3\dfrac{dx}{dt}-5t^4=0$$

into a system of first order equation.

I can't understand how to proceed.

Comment: Let $v = x'$ so that $v' = x''$, proceed similarly by letting $w = v'$.

Answer (score 1):

We are given:

$$\dfrac{d^3x}{dt^3}+t\dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2t^3\dfrac{dx}{dt}-5t^4=0$$

As hinted at by @ShuhaoCao, we can proceed as follows:

- $x_1 = x \implies x_1' = x' = x_2$
- $x_2 = x' \implies x_2' = x'' = x_3$
- $x_3 = x'' \implies x_3' = x''' = -t x'' -2t^3 x' +5t^4 = -t x_3 -2t^3x_2+5t^4$

So, our new system is:

$$\begin{align}
x_1' & = x_2 \\
x_2' & = x_3 \\
x_3' & = -t x_3 -2t^3x_2+5t^4 
\end{align}$$

Note, if we had been given initial conditions, they would similarly follow as:

- $x(0) = a \implies x_1(0) = a$
- $x'(0) = b \implies x_2(0) = b$
- $x''(0) = c \implies x_3(0) = c$

Comment: ...And a very nice layout and presentation, too!

Comment: Indeed! Back at you!